# C: inputs to a function left unaltered by the function

Tags: c, function, scope

I have a function in C that I want to output four different values, so rather than using `return` in my function I decided have four different variables as arguments to the function that would carry their values out of the function back into my `main` code.  I figured if I defined the variables in `main` and fed them to my other function, they would have whatever value the function gave them after exiting the function.  This does not happen though.  The variables end up having a value of 0 or close to 0 (like, around 10^-310).

Do I have to declare my variables in a different way/with a different scope to allow them to keep the values they had in a function after exiting the function?  Or is there a way to `return` multiple values in a function?

Here's an excerpt of the relative code:

```
void PeakShift_FWHM_Finder(double fwhml,double fwhmr,double peak, double max)
{
  ...//stuff happens to these variables
}

int main()
{
  double fwhml,fwhmr,peak,max;

  ...//other stuff to other variables

  PeakShift_FWHM_Finder(fwhml,fwhmr,peak,max)
  //These four variables have the right values inside the function
  //but once they leave the function they do not keep those values.

  ...//code continues...
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called **Passing by reference**

To achieve that, you need to change your declaration to take pointers to the variables. For example

```
void foo(int * x) {
    (*x)++;
}
```

Then, you can simply invoke that function passing values to it through their address.

```
int main() {
    int i = 10;
    foo(&i);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

What this does is passes the address location of the variable to be modified and the function directly modifies the variable at that address.

Comment: Inside `foo` the expression should be `(*x)++`.  Otherwise you are doing pointer arithmetic, which is not what is intended.

Comment: I guess that is what happens when you type in answers at 4 in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: @Shredderroy, would the original x++ point to the next `int`-sized block of bytes in the memory?

Comment: @Joshua Yes, it would.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't pass-by-reference (and C doesn't support pass-by-reference, either). What you're doing here is pass-by-value, but the thing you're passing is a pointer to the object you're interested in. You get pretty nearly the same effect, but it isn't quite the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Use pointers instead.

```
void PeakShift_FWHM_Finder(double *fwhml,double *fwhmr,double *peak, double *max)
{
  ...//stuff happens to these variables
    // REMEMBER TO DEAL WITH (*var_name) INSTEAD OF var_name!
}

int main()
{
  double fwhml,fwhmr,peak,max;

  ...//other stuff to other variables

  PeakShift_FWHM_Finder(&fwhml,&fwhmr,&peak,&max)
  //These four variables have the right values inside the function
  //but once they leave the function they do not keep those values.

  ...//code continues...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do exactly what you say above, but then I get the following errors at compiling from inside the function: `error: invalid operands to binary < (have ‘double *’ and ‘double’)` and `error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double *’ from type ‘double’`. Do I need to put a `*` with every use of the variables? That would make sense I guess, because you need to point directly to the value in the memory in the function as you've said before.

Comment: Yes, you need to dereference each variable inside the `PeakShift` function.  Hence my comment in upper case.